# Clustering service Configuration help

Tags: windows-cluster, failovercluster, cluster

When setting up Windows Cluster, should "clustering service" run as a "domain account" or "Local System" account?

Comment: what version of os? w2k8r2 its system only!

Answer (score 1):

Running it under the local system account should be fine.  It's what we do here.

Comment: Us as well. Works good.